# Как после отправки формы аяксом остаться на странице и сделать всплывающее окно?

Tags: php, javascript, html

помогите пожалуйста.
Стоит задача после отправки формы не перенаправлять на страницу mydomain.ru/mail.php, а вызвать всплывашку в виде MagnificPopup
Вот код JS

```js
  $("form#order2").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php", //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).submit(function() {
      $.magnificPopup.open({ 
        items: {
        src: '<div class="js-popup"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br /> Ваша заявка принята. <br />Наш менеджер перезвонит Вам в течении 30 минут</div>', // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
        type: 'inline'
        }
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
```

В конце mail.php
есть (отрывок)

```js
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: index.html');
}
```

Тут ума хватает перенаправить только на свою страницу обратно.
Буду очень признателен за решение ( сайт для себя делаю)

Comment: у вас есть `echo 'Error';`, соответственно можете вместо header писать `echo 'Success';`....... В `ajax` в методе `success` или `done` проверять ответ от сервера, и если он `Success` - значит показываете всплывающее окно

Comment: подскажите как это реализовать, когда я прописываю метод success: мне при компиляции выдает ошибку

Comment: .....а что пишите? и что за ошибку?

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решился двумя строчками и методом event.preventDefault();

```js
$("form#testing").submit(function(event) { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php", //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      $.magnificPopup.open({ 
        items: {
        src: '<div class="js-popup"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br />Ваша заявка принята. <br />Наш менеджер перезвонит Вам в течении 30 минут</div>', // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
        type: 'inline'
        }
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
  });
```